# Is there such a thing as a variable variable in CSS?

Tags: css, css-variables

I've got a lot of styles going on. Entire blocks that get used depending on what page the user is on. But I'd like to condense that down to one block. For instance, here's a snippet of a CSS block:

```
h1.index { color: var(--index-page-color); }
p.index { color: var(--index-page-color); }
```

There are a few more styles like this totaling about 30 lines, and each page has its own block: index, connect, interviews, friends, merchandise, subscribe, etc. etc. This can get bulky. What I'd like to do is some variable variables, something like:

```
h1.var(--page-name) { color: var(--var(--page-name)-page-color); }
p.var(--page-name) { color: var(--var(--page-name)-page-color); }
```

to reduce all that CSS down to one block. Is this possible, and if so, what's the syntax?

Comment: This is not possible with CSS, look at SASS/LESS

Answer (score -2):

Wrap each page in it's own div container then make the different code based on the div container name and do it all in one css page

Like this:

Homepage

```
<div class="homepagecontainer">
All your page content goes here
<div>
```

Do this for each page but a different container name

Then do your css as follows

```
.homepagecontainer h1{
Color:black;
}

.aboutuscontainer h1{
Color:blue;
}
```

And do that for each page then you have different css for each page